# Configure SSI for localhost

Tags: apache2, configuration, localhost

I'm trying to use SSIs to append a single copy of a jQuery mobile collapsible to multiple divs.  They cannot be cloned, and jQuery get/prepend is not working, so I'm resorting to this.

I have pointed `apache2.conf` to `httpd.conf` in the same directory.

In `httpd.conf` I have:

```
#<Directory /var/www/>
        Options +Includes
        XBitHack on
#</Directory>
```

with and without `#` or `/var/www/`.

I have set the file with this failing SSI code

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

to executable in a subdirectory.

I am on 13.10.  The IP of Apache hasn't been set and defaults to `127.0.0.1`.  I have changed the port to `8080`.  Otherwise, I have changed nothing.

I access the server via `http://localhost:8080`.

How can my intent be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it at this random [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182579).

For the unsecured site, this code

```
<Directory /var/www/mySubdirectory>
    Options +Includes
    XBitHack on
</Directory>
```

needs to go in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

For the secure site, the code probably needs to go in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.